# Protractor, helper function is not receiving update value

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

I am e2e testing an edit function in my app. The user clicks on a row, then clicks on an edit button. From there they are brought to a menu where they can edit their creditials. This function here:

```
export async function findRow(rows, matcher) {

    const relevantRow = await rows.filter(row => {

        return row.getText().then(text => {

            return text.includes(matcher);

        });

    }).first();

    return relevantRow;
```

Retrieves the row based on whatever value I pass.
In my spec class I test it like so:

```
  it('should edit the user', async function()  {

page.editUser();

const row = await findRow(page.rows, 'testEmail@testEmail')

expect(await row.getText()).toContain('editedName')
```

Now my test fails saying something like expected 'OriginalName' to contain editedName. On screen as I watch my test automated through Chrome, I see the value change. I have the browser wait a little too so that the function can grab the values. This leads me to believe that my function is grabbing the row before the edit function. I am not sure if this is the case though, so any input would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grabbing the row before your editation, because your `editUser()` function is running asynchronously, because the most Protractor functions are asynchronous as you know ;-) .

Because of that you need to call the function with `await`:

```
await page.editUser();
```

And mark you `editUser` function with `async`.

So the further execution waits until your function finishes.